# Trouble with comparing Char from two different strings

Tags: java, char, comparison

The program is suppossed to be a glossary test with 10 different words. My code is working except one thing, and that being a function allowing the user to get an output saying "almost correct, the correct answer is ..." if some of the char is correct.

For example; Correct answer is house.

```
user writes: housq -> output = "Almost correct, the correct answer is..."

user writes hsasa -> output = "Wrong, the correct answer is..."
```

My plan is to put the "Almost correct" through int count, in a span between the values 1-3.

But with this loop:
It only counts correctly spelled words, for example

```
Correct word is house.

input -> house -> count=5

input -> housa -> count=0.
```

I'm new to Java and I apologize to everyone for potential bad code.

```
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = "";
    String[] eng = {"car", "house", "run", "blue", "bake", "jump", "swim", "moon", "road", "kind"};
    String[] swe = {"bil", "hus", "springa", "blå", "baka", "hoppa", "simma", "måne", "väg", "snäll"};
    int result = 0;
    int word = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int low = 2;
    int high = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < swe.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(swe[i]);
        inputString = scanner.nextLine().trim();

        if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(eng[i])) {
            word++;
            result++;
            System.out.println("Korrekt! " + result + " rätt av " + word + " ord.");

            for (int j = 0; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
                if (inputString.charAt(j) == eng[i].charAt(j)) {
                    ++count;

                }
            }
                      if(count >= low){
                    System.out.println("Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är " + eng[i]);
                    word++;
                }


                if(count > low && count < high){
                    System.out.println("Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är " + eng[i]);
                    word++;
                }
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("fel, rätt svar är " + eng[i]);
            word++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);

        if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            System.out.println("Du svarade på totalt " + word + " glosor och hade " + result + " rätt. Välkommen åter!");

            System.exit(0);

        }

        count = 0;
    }
}
```

}}

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Could you please paste your eng declaration

Used like `eng[i]` in if condition.

Comment: You should post more of your code because looking at the for loop I can't see why you wouldn't have a count of 4 when evaluating "housa".

I'd also recommend you to be aware of spaces (maybe trim() the user input)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your this code fragment like this and i get the output correct.
Here is what i have tried

```
String inputString = "housr";
        String eng = "house";
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
            if(inputString.charAt(j) == eng.charAt(j)){
            ++count;
           }}
        System.out.println(count);
```

I got output as **4**

And what are you trying, please paste your logic and the data also

Comment: I don't know what I do wrong, but when i javadoced the first "If statement" the count was correct, housa got count = 4. Sorry about the swedish in the output messages.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your if condition

```
if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(eng[i]))
```

it checks for equals condition, if both your input string and eng[i] are equal then only your code executes and in your case your input in **housq** and you never find that word in eng array it skips the for loop and count will be your initialized value i;e, 0

Is there any specific reason you are using that if condition

And at this line

```
if (inputString.charAt(j) == eng[i].charAt(j))
```

If your input string size and eng[i] string size is not equal than you will get **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception .

With slight changes in your code i can make it work to get your desired output

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = "";
        String[] eng = {"car", "house", "run", "blue", "bake", "jump", "swim", "moon", "road", "kind"};
        String[] swe = {"bil", "hus", "springa", "blå", "baka", "hoppa", "simma", "måne", "väg", "snäll"};
        int result = 0;
        int word = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int low = 2;
        int high = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < swe.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(swe[i]);
            inputString = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(eng[i])) {
                word++;
                result++;
                System.out.println("Korrekt! " + result + " rätt av " + word + " ord.");
            }


            if(inputString.length() == eng[i].length()){

                for (int j = 0; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
                    if (inputString.charAt(j) == eng[i].charAt(j)) {
                        ++count;

                    }
                }
            }
                          if(count >= low){
                        System.out.println("Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är " + eng[i]);
                        word++;
                    }


                    if(count > low && count < high){
                        System.out.println("Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är " + eng[i]);
                        word++;
                    }
            if (count == 0) {
                System.out.println("fel, rätt svar är " + eng[i]);
                word++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);

            if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
                System.out.println("Du svarade på totalt " + word + " glosor och hade " + result + " rätt. Välkommen åter!");

                System.exit(0);

            }

            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here my input is **housq**

Output i got is

```
fel, rätt svar är car
0
Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är house
4
fel, rätt svar är run
0
fel, rätt svar är blue
0
fel, rätt svar är bake
0
fel, rätt svar är jump
0
fel, rätt svar är swim
0
fel, rätt svar är moon
0
fel, rätt svar är road
0
fel, rätt svar är kind
0
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time and help. What your output says now is "Wrong, correct answer is..." except on word 2 "house" where the output is exactly what i'm after

Comment: The plan is. output -> swe[0]. If input is correct to eng[0] -> "Correct! word++ and result ++. If input is close but not correct for example count = 2,3 or 4 -> "Almost, the correct answer is..." word++ and then the last alternative is "Wrong" Word++.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void spel() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = "";
    String[] eng = {"car", "house", "run", "blue", "bake", "jump", "swim", "moon", "road", "kind"};
    String[] swe = {"bil", "hus", "springa", "blå", "baka", "hoppa", "simma", "måne", "väg", "snäll"};
    int result = 0;
    int word = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int low = 2;
    int high = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < swe.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(swe[i]);
        inputString = scanner.nextLine().trim();

        if(inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(eng[i])) {
            word++;
            result++;
            System.out.println("Korrekt! " + result + " rätt av " + word + " ord.");
        }

            for (int j = 0; j < inputString.length(); j++) {
                if (inputString.charAt(j) == eng[i].charAt(j)) {
                    ++count;

                }
            }
                      if(count >= low){
                    System.out.println("Nästan rätt, korrekt svar är " + eng[i]);
                    word++;
                }

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("fel, rätt svar är " + eng[i]);
            word++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);

        if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            System.out.println("Du svarade på totalt " + word + " glosor och hade " + result + " rätt. Välkommen åter!");

            System.exit(0);

        }

        count = 0;

}
```

}}

With this updated code. I get the correct answer when most of the Char is correct. For example housa = 4 -> "Almost correct...."

But i still have the problem when difference in size in inputString and eng[i].length. And also when the inputString is the correct answer both "Correct message" and "Almost" shows..